# How to split a panda's column with conditional

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Log df, in that df i have the column Description. Looks like.

```
Description
Machine x : Turn off
Another action here
Another action here
Machine y : Turn off
Machine x : Turn on
Another action here
```

And I need split just rows with ":"

Like:

```
Description               Machine           Action
Machine x : Turn off      Machine x         Turn off
Another action here
Another action here
Machine y : Turn off      Machine y         Turn off
Machine x : Turn on       Machine x         Turn on
Another action here
```

I already tried:

```
s = df["Description"].apply(lambda x:x.split(":"))
df["Action"] = s.apply(lambda x: x[1])
df["Machine"] = s.apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

And something with "startswith".

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.extract` with a suitable `regex`. This will find all values around the `:` (also stripping the spaces around the colon):

```
df[['Machine', 'Action']] = df.Description.str.extract('(.*) : (.*)',expand=True)

>>> df
            Description    Machine    Action
0  Machine x : Turn off  Machine x  Turn off
1   Another action here        NaN       NaN
2   Another action here        NaN       NaN
3  Machine y : Turn off  Machine y  Turn off
4   Machine x : Turn on  Machine x   Turn on
5   Another action here        NaN       NaN

# df[['Machine', 'Action']] = df.Description.str.extract('(.*) : (.*)',expand=True).fillna('')
```

Answer (score 2):

Given a dataframe

```
>>> df
            Description
0  Machine x : Turn off
1   Another action here
2   Another action here
3  Machine y : Turn off
4   Machine x : Turn on
5   Another action here
```

I'd approach this via `Series.str.split(splitter, expand=True)`.

```
>>> has_colon = df['Description'].str.contains(':')
>>> df[['Machine', 'Action']] = df.loc[has_colon, 'Description'].str.split('\s*:\s*', expand=True)
>>> df
            Description    Machine    Action
0  Machine x : Turn off  Machine x  Turn off
1   Another action here        NaN       NaN
2   Another action here        NaN       NaN
3  Machine y : Turn off  Machine y  Turn off
4   Machine x : Turn on  Machine x   Turn on
5   Another action here        NaN       NaN
```

If you prefer empty strings, you can replace the `NaN` cells via

```
>>> df.fillna('')
            Description    Machine    Action
0  Machine x : Turn off  Machine x  Turn off
1   Another action here                     
2   Another action here                     
3  Machine y : Turn off  Machine y  Turn off
4   Machine x : Turn on  Machine x   Turn on
5   Another action here
```

Answer (score 2):

Just using `split` with `expand=True`

```
df[['Machine', 'Action']] =df.Description.str.split(':',expand=True).dropna()
df
            Description     Machine     Action
0  Machine x : Turn off  Machine x    Turn off
1   Another action here         NaN        NaN
2   Another action here         NaN        NaN
3  Machine y : Turn off  Machine y    Turn off
4   Machine x : Turn on  Machine x     Turn on
5   Another action here         NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

With `pd.Series.str.extract` function and specific regex pattern (covers potential multiple spaces around `:` separator):

```
In [491]: df
Out[491]: 
            Description
0  Machine x : Turn off
1   Another action here
2   Another action here
3  Machine y : Turn off
4   Machine x : Turn on
5   Another action here

In [492]: pd.concat([df, df.Description.str.extract('(?P<Machine>[^:]+)\s+:\s+(?P<Action>[^:]+)').fillna('')], axis=1)
Out[492]: 
            Description    Machine    Action
0  Machine x : Turn off  Machine x  Turn off
1   Another action here                     
2   Another action here                     
3  Machine y : Turn off  Machine y  Turn off
4   Machine x : Turn on  Machine x   Turn on
5   Another action here
```

Answer (score 1):

`StringMethods` are useful and convenient but usually *do not perform well.*

I'd recommend using the default constructor and pure-python string handling

```
df[['Machine', 'Action']] = pd.DataFrame([x.split(':') for x in df.Description]).dropna()
```

Timings are better than `.str` accessor options.

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000)
%timeit pd.DataFrame([x.split(':') for x in df.Description]).dropna()
4.47 ms ± 252 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.Description.str.split(':',expand=True).dropna()
14.9 ms ± 323 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.Description.str.extract('(.*) : (.*)',expand=True)
16.6 ms ± 393 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit pd.concat([df, df.Description.str.extract('(?P<Machine>[^:]+)\s+:\s+(?P<Action>[^:]+)').fillna('')], axis=1)
22.5 ms ± 448 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposition is:

```
msk = df.Description.str.contains(':')
df[['Machine', 'Action']] = df.Description.str.split(':', 1, expand=True).where(msk, '')
```

First create a mask - which rows can receive non-empty values.

Then perform actual substitution, only for rows where the mask is true.
Other rows (actually all new columns) receive an empty string.